# Use knowledge:articleList hasMoreVar Attribute in rendered Expression

Tags: visualforce, knowledge, pagination

The [`knowledge:articleList` component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_knowledge_articleList.htm) has an attribute named `hasMoreVar`. This attribute (similar to `articleVar`) allows me to declare a variable that returns **true** if the current article is *not* the last article in the list, and **false** if the current article is the last article.

Outside of the `knowledge:articleList` I have pagination controls, namely a Previous Page button and a Next Page button. In theory I would love to define my button like this:

```
<knowledge:articleList ...
                       hasMoreVar="hasMore"
                       ...>
    ...
</knowledge:articleList>

<apex:commandButton action="{!nextPage}"
                    rendered="{!hasMore}"
                    value="Next Page"/>
```

However, the **hasMore** variable is only effective within the context of `knowledge:articleList`, and my pagination controls are placed outside of the article loop.

How can I wire the `hasMoreVar` attribute in the article list to the `rendered` attribute on my button?

Comment: That won't be possible, as it is maintained by VF engine. I will create a custom solution to be depended on these vf tags. Go Lightning!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `hasMoreVar` attribute depends on JavaScript. The approach isn't totally terrible, and being able to avoid Apex and leverage native security settings is a huge plus. In short, the solution has two parts.

1. Declare a variable or property before the `knowledge:articleList`, and default it to **false**.
2. Include a `script` element inside the `knowledge:articleList` which simply sets the variable or property to the `hasMoreVar` value.
3. When the page loads (e.g., using jQuery and `$(document).ready()` to handle the event), check for the presence of the variable and use this information to toggle elements like the **Next Page** button.

### Visualforce Code Sample

```
<div id="searchResults">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var hasMore = false;  // Until proven otherwise
    </script>

    <knowledge:articleList articleVar="article"
                           hasMoreVar="hasMoreArticles"
                           keyword="{!keyword}"
                           language="{!language}"
                           pageNumber="{!pageNumber}"
                           pageSize="{!pageSize}">
        ...
        <script>
        lastResultNumber++;
        hasMore = {!hasMoreArticles};  // Will be false for last article
        </script>
    </knowledge:articleList>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (hasMore) {
            // Toggle visibility of visual elements such as the
            // Next Page button in a pagination control.
        }
    });
    </script>
</div>
```